# Transactions in riak

Tags: transactions, erlang, riak

I'm using riak in a product and encounter the following question on design.

Assume client A and client B sign up at the same time with the same email/login_id. How to handle it in riak.

In traditional db, we will use transactions deal with it.

As a newbie to riak, who can tell me how to handle it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can't handle this in Riak in a transactional way (Riak 2.0 might be able to do it with consistent writes through riak-ensemble). Just bumping the consistency levels is not enough to get the consistency you want.

So either your design has to live with the problem, or you have to solve the multiple-login problem later on when you realize two users created the same login at the same time.

My approach would be to have a serialized writer for these things. User creation isn't common. And a serialized writer can always guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: It may be worth looking at riak Stanchion which looks like an implementation of the serializer described. http://docs.basho.com/riak/cs/2.1.1/theory/stanchion/

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your question is pretty broad, Riak handles the consistency issue using version clock and other synchronization methods. Are you using single node or distributed nodes ? Anyways the Consistency provided by Riak is configurable (Ofcourse tuning for more consustency will impact other parameters, remember CAP ?). 
Check out  [THIS](http://a-developer-life.blogspot.in/2011/10/riak-key-value-store-with-configurable.html) , might help you understanding more about your issue in general.

UPDATE:
Besides what I pointed in my comment, since you are dealing with only a single node, you can queue up the requests in erlang's standard message queue (gen_server ?). Scaling your service to multiple nodes will again cause complications (a lot of) if you want to guarantee "transactional" behavior.

Comment: Thanks. single node. I read the article you mentioned, and still have no idea on how to resolve my question. Can you explain in details?

Comment: I have not worked on Riak directly, but upon searching the docs, found how this can be resolved on the client side. http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/theory/concepts/Vector-Clocks/ AND http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.2.0/references/appendices/concepts/. Check for "Concurrent writes" and "conflict resolution" resp.